# Botões com modais automáticos com base no JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

Olá

Eu estou a fazer um site que constrói imagens e modais com base no Json mas eu não consigo fazer o script que faz com que copie a primeira div e com base no números de casos, vão aparecendo do lado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já tinha feito algo parecido com isso mas com bonecos, tentei usar o mesmo código mas com class, const e id diferentes mas não resulta...

código dos bonecos:

```js
const urlIcon = './imagens/personagem7.png';
const imagem = `<img src="${urlIcon}" />`;

const imagens = Array.from({
        length: Number(arrayResultados.length)
    }).reduce((html) => html + imagem, '');
    $('#images').html(imagens);
```

O que devia acontecer era criar aquele icon consoante o numero de vitimas no json e essa div tinha um link para um modal especifico que também era criado consoante o numero de vitimas e com as informações do json, se alguem me conseguir ajudar com o codigo eu agradecia ainda sou novo nisto do javascript...

HTMl da pagina (div e modal):

```html
<div class="imagemavatar">
                    <img type="button" src="./imagens/avatar2.png" class="img-fluid" data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#exampleModalCenter1">
                </div>
                
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
            aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <!-- hearder -->

                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Lúcia Rodrigues</h5>

                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <!-- body -->

                        <div class="imagemdocaso">
                            <img src="./imagens/avatar2.png" width="100%" height="100%">
                        </div>

                        <div class="descricao">
                            <p>
                                <b>Data do caso:</b> 05 de janeiro de 2019 <br>
                                <b>Nome da vítima:</b> Lúcia Rodrigues <br>
                                <b>Idade da Vítima:</b> 48 anos <br>
                                <b>Localidade:</b> Lagoa, Algarve
                            </p>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <!-- footer -->
                        <a href="https://www.cmjornal.pt/exclusivos/detalhe/cacador-mata-mulher-por-ciumes-doentios"
                            class="noticia btn btn-outline-warning buttonlink" target="_blank">Noticia completa</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

o modal que já lá esta foi feito a mão e as informações que lá estão também eu gostava de fazer isso mas automático junto com o JSON

Json:

```js
[
    {
        "Nome": "Lucia Rodrigues",
        "Idade": 48,
        "Distrito": "Faro",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Feminino",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim",
        "id": 1,
        "longitude": -8.483230,
        "latitude": 37.147150
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Nome Desconhecido",
        "Idade": 46,
        "Distrito": "Açores",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Feminino",
        "RecursoArma": "Não",
        "id": 2,
        "longitude": -27.210329,
        "latitude": 38.721210
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Vera Silva",
        "Idade": 30,
        "Distrito": "Setúbal",
        "Faixa Etaria": "26-35",
        "Faixa": "faixaC",
        "Sexo": "Feminino",
        "RecursoArma": "Não",
        "id": 3,
        "longitude": -9.179570,
        "latitude": 38.667440
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Maria Eufrázia",
        "Idade": 83,
        "Distrito": "Évora",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Feminino",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim",
        "id": 4,
        "longitude": -7.411580,
        "latitude": 38.621020
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Luzia Rosado",
        "Idade": 80,
        "Distrito": "Évora",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Feminino",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim",
        "id": 5,
        "longitude": -7.411580,
        "latitude": 38.621020
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Fernanda",
        "Idade": 70,
        "Distrito": "Lisboa",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Feminino",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim",
        "id": 6,
        "longitude": -9.250460,
        "latitude": 38.706230
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Nome Desconhecido",
        "Idade": 48,
        "Distrito": "Santarém",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Feminino",
        "RecursoArma": "Não",
        "id": 7,
        "longitude": -8.682080,
        "latitude": 39.235370
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Marina Mendes",
        "Idade": 25,
        "Distrito": "Viseu",
        "Faixa Etaria": "18-25",
        "Faixa": "faixaB",
        "Sexo": "Feminino",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim",
        "id": 8,
        "longitude": -7.617740,
        "latitude": 40.985050
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Helena Cabrita",
        "Idade": 60,
        "Distrito": "Setúbal",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Feminino",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim",
        "id": 9,
        "longitude": -7.933170,
        "latitude": 40.668580
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Lara",
        "Idade": 2,
        "Distrito": "Setúbal",
        "Faixa Etaria": "0-17",
        "Faixa": "faixaA",
        "Sexo": "Feminino",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim",
        "id": 10,
        "longitude": -7.933170,
        "latitude": 40.668580
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Fernando Cruz",
        "Idade": 67,
        "Distrito": "Porto",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Masculino",
        "RecursoArma": "Não",
        "id": 11,
        "longitude": -8.629105,
        "latitude": 41.157944
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Ana Maria Silva",
        "Idade": 53,
        "Distrito": "Santarém",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Feminino",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim",
        "id": 12,
        "longitude": -8.489080,
        "latitude": 39.402700
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Ana Paula",
        "Idade": 40,
        "Distrito": "Braga",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Feminino",
        "RecursoArma": "Não",
        "id": 13,
        "longitude": -8.091410,
        "latitude": 41.681510
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Heila Lopes",
        "Idade": 44,
        "Distrito": "Lisboa",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Feminino",
        "RecursoArma": "Não",
        "id": 14,
        "longitude": -9.309280,
        "latitude": 39.067570
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Sónia Ribeiro",
        "Idade": 37,
        "Distrito": "Algarve",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Feminino",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim",
        "id": 15,
        "longitude": -7.414600,
        "latitude": 37.192760
    }
]
```

Comment: Vc quer repetir só a imagem ou a `<div class="imagemavatar">` toda?

Comment: @Sam a div toda que depois ao associar o json as divs e as modais cada um vai ter a sua informação. o objetivo e fazer com que o json cria-se ele as divs e as modais com o numero e o conteudo dos casos do json